# MSAL ASP.NET Web API returns 401 on Angular HTTP GET request

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm fairily new to MSAL and I can't figure out why I get returned a 401 when accessing my Web API with the `MsalInterceptor` configured as a provider in `app.module.ts`.

For reference, my `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { MsalModule, MsalInterceptor } from "@azure/msal-angular";
import { BrowserCacheLocation } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { NavbarComponent } from './views/partials/navbar/navbar.component';

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: environment.azure.clientId,
        authority: environment.azure.authority,
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/profile'
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
      },
    }, {
      popUp: !isIE,
      consentScopes: [
        'user.read',
        'openid',
        'profile',
        'api://xxx/xxx/xxx'
      ],
      unprotectedResources: [],
      protectedResourceMap: [
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/', ['user.read']],
        ['https://localhost:44312/weatherforecast/getTest', ['api://xxx/xxx/xxx']]
      ],
      extraQueryParameters: {},
    }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MsalInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I set up a service with the request containing following function:

```js
async getForecast() {
    return await this.http.get('https://localhost:44312/weatherForecast/getTest').toPromise();
}
```

The WeatherForecast "getTest" function looks like this:

```cs
[HttpGet("getTest")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
   return Ok("test");
}
```

Obviously, the controller itself is decored with the `[Authorize]` tag.

I suppose the access token possibly doesn't get wrapped around the HTTP request(?) although as the Microsoft Docs describe, the access token handling happens automatically within the interceptor itself.

Also to note: I have no trouble making requests to the Graph API (GET request to /me/photo/$value).

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your custom API in azure? You have to register your API in azure in order to get these Client id and app id.

In order to use MSAL, you have to follow a few steps in Azure:

1. Register your API in azure. After the success registration, go to "Expose an API" and create a new scope (api://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/user_access).
2. Register your Application in Azure. Be sure the "Token Id" and "Access token" options are checked when registering your URI Redirection. Then go to "Api Permissions" -> "Add a permission" -> My Apis -> Select you created in 1. (api://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/user_access). Doing this, your app can access to your api :
3. In your App Module, fill the "protected resource map" option with the api scopes created in 1.
4. In your api, you have to fill the clientId, TenantId and enable cors.

Doing this, your app can make petitions to your api

This post will guide you to the light

https://manojchoudhari.wordpress.com/2020/05/05/angular-app-and-azure-ad-protected-web-api-using-msal/

Sorry for my bad english, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I did this when I set up my project so thats not where the problem lies.